# Firestore update using react js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am workin  on react js project with firebase **(firestore Database)**.In project I Get input from user(email,name,address)..I want to update the address and name in firebase using email as key.
but dont know.I am using update function and help from google but they gave me error I am very thankful to you.. please help me

Answer (score 1):

**./config.js**

*//Create a config file and export db*

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '',
  authDomain: '',
  projectId: '',
  storageBucket: '',
  messagingSenderId: '',
  appId: '',
  measurementId: '${config.measurementId}',
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth();
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

export { db, auth, provider };
```

**YourComponent.js**

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import { collection, query, where, getDocs, updateDoc} from "firebase/firestore";
import {db} from './config';

export default function YourComponent(){

const [email,setEmail] = useState('');
const [address,setAddress] = useState('');
const [name,setName]  = useState('');

const updateUser = async () => {
 const userRef = query(collection(db, "users"), where("email", "==", email));
 const findUsers = await getDocs(userRef);
 findUsers.forEach( async (user) => {
  const getUser = doc(db, 'users', user.id);
  await updateDoc(getUser, {
   name: name,
   address: address
  });
 });
}

return <Component />
}
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Though i would have prefered more information about this like code snippet of your component so that i can be specific but i will provide you general idea which you can easily use

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { collection, query, where, getDocs, updateDoc} from "firebase/firestore";



function SomeComponent(){

    const [email,setEmail] = useState('');
    const [address,setAddress] = useState('');
    const [name,setName]  = useState('');

    const UpdateUserInfo = async()=>{
        const q = query(collection(db, "users"), where("email", "==", email));

        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        let docID = '';
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        // if email is you primary key then only document will be fetched so it is safe to continue, this line will get the documentID of user so that we can update it
          docID = doc.id;
        });
        const user = doc(db, "users", docID);

        // Set the "capital" field of the city 'DC'
        await updateDoc(user, {
            name: name,
            address: address
        });
    }


    return (
        <>
         {
         //some ui here that will set email, name and address, and you have to call UpdateUserInfo before it works
         }
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Face Error :
'doc' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: can you share code snippet so that i can check the issue,